# i cant assign updated token in my interceptor service in Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I get a typescript error in my interceptor that says that

> Cannot find name 'authReq'.

How can i convert my code so that my interceptor correctly catches the access token set by the register component and typescript shows no error?

**User.Service.ts** -> here i declare the access_token as BehavioralSubject

```
  access_token = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

**Register.component.ts -> here i successfully assign the value to access_token**

```
 onRegister(form){
    this.httpService.registerByEmail(this.email, this.password )
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.httpService.loginByEmail(this.email, this.password)
        .subscribe(response1 => {
          this.userService.access_token.next(response1['access_token']);
        })
    })
  }
```

**Auth.Interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// services
import { UserService } from '../../services/data/user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
  authToken;

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    this.userService.access_token.subscribe(
      token => {
      this.authToken = token;
        const authReq = req.clone({
          headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authToken}`)
        });
        return authReq;
      }
    )
    return next.handle(authReq);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, there is no `authReq` outside the `access_token` subscription. Also you are doing : `return next.handle(authReq);` this statement in itself is Synchronous, so this won't wait for your subscription to complete.

I don't know if it suits your needs, but what I think you should do is:
Rather than the subscription, do a `map` for `access_token` and return the `next` under the map. And then `susbscribe` to the `intercept` under whichever function is calling it.

```
return this.userService.access_token.map(
  token => {
  this.authToken = token;
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authToken}`)
    });
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

return this.userService.access_token.flatMap(
  token => {
    this.authToken = token;
    const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authToken}`)
       });
       return next.handle(authReq);  
   }
)}
```